# Why can Tomcat not find my web application?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I have a Java Web Project I'am trying to run on my Tomcat host.

I configured my Tomcat host so that Eclipse recognizes that I can run web apps on it.

This is what my web app structure looks like. (after doing the copy mentioned below)

[image]

I believe I have all the necessary config files, etc. However when I run my project, I keep getting a

HTTP Status 404 /AirlineReservationSystem/ requested resource is not available error.

From reading about [server.xml](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-server-xml-and-web-xml), I believe the problem lies here because it controls server specific configurations(like telling the server where to find AirlineReservationSystem is)

So I take a look at that and see this config setting

```
Context docBase="AirlineReservationSystem" path="/AirlineReservationSystem" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:AirlineReservationSystem"/>
```

I read from [Apache Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html) that docbase defines the directory of the web application. My thought process after reading that is that my web app isn't being found because it is not located inside the Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost-config. So I copy my web app into that folder but now  when I run the copy, it doesn't load anything.

Does anyone know what the issue is? Why Tomcat can't find AirlineReservationSystem? From my limited experience with Tomcat, my assumption could very well be wrong.(that you have to put it inside localconfig with servers.xml)

Comment: **AirlineReservationSystem** I think I will walk ;-)  You should hardly every need to modify your server.xml

Comment: As per your link that you gave us **it is NOT recommended to place <Context> elements directly in the server.xml file**

Comment: @ScaryWombat its actually not. It's inside a Host element. I just didn't include it

Comment: @ScaryWombat Do you know where I should look to resolve this or of a way to locate all resources on localhost?

Comment: Don't copy files into Server (it sounds from your description that that may be what you did). Delete anything there you copied that way, or better yet just delete the server and add it back so it has nothing in it. Right-click the Tomcat entry under Servers and select "Add and Remove"; you'll get a dialog box with server-enabled applications on the left and those that have been added to the server on the right. Move yours from left to right, then run.  Alternately, right-click the project in the Project Explorer and select "Debug / Debug on Server".

Comment: ... and the first thing you should check is the tomcat logs, it is likely to tell you if something has gone wrong with the deployment, otherwise you are just calling it wrong.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I navigated to the logs and all it has are get statements like 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Dec/2016:17:50:24 -0800] "GET /AirlineReservationSystem/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1044. So I'am calling the thing wrong?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Do you see any issues in my web.xml? Here is a collabedit for it - http://collabedit.com/7rb3f. I double checked all the package names, etc.

Comment: Are you following @arcy instructions?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes I did. I did the add remove, deleted the folder I copied into Servers, etc. I am thinking the problem has to do with my web.xml then which controls routes?

Comment: when you start tomcat in eclipse there should be a whole lot of console output - check to make sure that there were no errors

Comment: @ScaryWombat I did that too. There's a bunch of config logs like Dec 15, 2016 6:09:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start but I don't think these are errors. Then the last message says server startup in .... Did you see anything off in my web.xml?

Comment: In the console log did you see `AirlineReservationSystem` ? I see that you do not have `welcome-files` tag in the web.xml so `/AirlineReservationSystem/` will go nowhere

Comment: @ScaryWombat I didn't see anything with regards to AirlineReservationSystem. This web app is based off https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-jax-cellar/blob/master/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml. In the starter code web.xml, he doesn't have welcome-files either

Answer (score 1):

please try this:

1. right click your project and choose Properties.
2. choose Web Project Settings and change the Context root to "/yourProjectName"

Comment: It is AirlineReservationSystem already. I didn't know about web project settings. Thanks!

Comment: New to this. Maven Web project in Eclipse with Tomcat was not getting recognized from browser. This setting actually fixed it. After 4 tough hours. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Do the following, and skip no steps:

1. stop the server
2. delete the server from eclipse
3. do a clean of your project
4. do a build of your project
5. add the server as a server in eclipse. Ensure that eclipse shows no
   application underneath the server after you've added it.
6. right-click on your project, select "Debug", and then "Debug on
   server". It will present a dialog asking you to choose the server on
   which to run it. Choose your newly configured tomcat server, and
   select the "do this every time" option.
7. Wait
8. Wait some more. Watch the console until it says "server startup in
   NNNNN msecs", or whatever it is.

Within 10 seconds after that, your application's first page should appear on eclipse's default browser (which defaults to its internal one).

If it does not, then before you do anything else, copy the entire log and paste it here; add it to your question, or put it in an "answer" to your question. Except for passwords and/or proprietary info, don't edit it, don't leave anything out.

Comment: btw, it is past my bedtime, I won't look at this until morning New York time.

Comment: This is the entire log - 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2016:20:01:46 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 994
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Dec/2016:20:01:46 -0800] "GET /backbone-jax-cellar/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1034

Comment: Fortunately for me, I don't live in NY, just in its time zone.  I know I said "log", but what I meant was "console". There should be lots of stuff in the eclipse console, with something like "INFO: Server startup in 17388 ms" near the bottom. That's the output I want. You can't put it in a comment, it will need to go in a code or block quote section in a question/answer block.