# Why is Jersey servlet mapping not working(not appending reservations)?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, jersey

This question is based off my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176198/why-can-tomcat-not-find-my-web-application) and this [starter code](https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-jax-cellar)

So I'am working through my issue and thanks to the comment by @arcy, have been taking a close look at the logs. Here's my logs when requesting all the reservations(as opposed to the starter code which requests all wines)

For configuration, I only changed web.xml(below) in locations to reflect my updated package names.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <!-- 
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>org.chris438</param-value>
    </init-param>
    -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>org.chris438;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My context root is backbone-jax-cellar-master(shown below and with project structure)
[image]

After making a few request to http://localhost:8080/backbone-jax-cellar-master/#reservations, this is what my logs look like

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Dec/2016:20:41:14 -0800] "GET /backbone-jax-cellar-master/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Dec/2016:20:41:26 -0800] "GET /backbone-jax-cellar-master/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
```

What I noticed right away was that it ignored my reservations resource completely and just routed to the default route. Does anyone know why this is happening? I defined ReservationResource(below) much similar to the starter code's WineResource which compiles and runs.

```
@Path("/reservations")
public class ReservationResource {
    ReservationDAO dao = new ReservationDAO();
}
```

Comment: why .../#reservations ? maybe loose the `#`?

Comment: that didn't work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your servlet is mapping to

```
<url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
```

Your url should include /api to get through the servlet.

```
http://localhost:8080/backbone-jax-cellar-master/api/reservations
```

and your resource

```
@Path("/api/reservations")
```

Comment: Yea your explanation makes sense. I made the changes but am now getting 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Dec/2016:13:11:21 -0800] "GET /backbone-jax-cellar-master/api/reservations HTTP/1.1" 404 1080

Comment: Which is actually good in that the Get request is being sent to the right url